how to use clickHandler with the default parameters
Problem: I try to make two routine on onClick; first routine is when accessed by click, second one is when triggered by direct calling. But i found syntax error when onClick handle function with default parameters.
Question: I wanna use one clickHandler function by using default parameter.
function Element() {
  const clickHandler = (isCall: boolean = false) => {
    if (isCall) {
      Routine 1
    }
    else {
      Routine 2
    }
  };
  return <button onClick={clickHandler} id={"someId"} />;
}

/**--------from other code, to trigger the routine 2-------**/
document.getElementById("someId").click(true); // <-this trigger the routine 2


document.getElementById("someId").click(true); is an invalid call. Or better, the parameter you have passed is ignored. click() does not accept parameters, you have only the event parameter in the click handler.

i solved this problem by using 'animatestart' EventListener. it's only event without any user interaction but call of the program. so i use it as routine 2 trigger. Thanks to your advise, i can call two functions from one component, inside of its scope.

By Default clickHandler function will recieve event object, but you want to recieve isCall argument.So you can use arrow function in onClick listener with no parameter.(your clickHandler will receive default parameter.)
   return <button onClick={()=>clickHandler()} id={"someId"} />;

